# Arithmetic using summary means of the MCMC chains, differ from when I do the arithmetic directly using each row of the MCMC chains

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, stan

I am trying to calculate the 'absolute risk difference' and 'needed to treat' (NNT). NNT is 1/(absolute risk difference) where the absolute risk difference is just the rate of an event in one intervention minus the rate of an event in another intervention.

I have the rates of the events in two interventions calculated in MCMC chains. Based on the MCMC summaries: the mean rate of events in intervention1 is 0.13 and the mean rate of events in intervention2 is 0.17.

If I manually calculate the absolute risk difference using these summary numbers written above I get 0.17 - 0.13 = 0.04 which makes sense.
If I mannually calculate the absolute risk difference using the 4 chains (excuse my noob coding below) I get the same answer which again makes sense.

```
# the absolute risk diffeence is the difference between the rate of 
# intervention1 and intervention2
RD <-   (parray[,,1] - parray[,,2])
RD <- as.data.frame(RD)
# combining the four chains 
RD_combined_df <- data.frame(RD_combined = c(RD[,1],RD[,2],RD[,3],RD[,4]  )
mean(RD_combined_df$RD_combined)
# mean returns  -0.04342125 which is expected
```

However, when I go to calculate NNT based on the same absolute event rates calculated above, I get unexpected summary statistics and I'm not sure which ones to go with.
Calculating NNT based on the mean event rate numbers above I get 1/(0.17-13) which = 1/0.04 which =23 and sounds about right in the context of the absolute event rates.
However when I calculate NNT using the 4 chains I get a dramatically different answer, and this answer does not seem to align with what we would expect based on the absolute risk difference.

```
# 1 over the absolute risk difference
NNT <-   1/((parray[,,1] - parray[,,2]))

# Combining the four chains 
NNT_combined_df <- data.frame(NNT_combined = c(NNT[,1],NNT[,2],NNT[,3],NNT[,4]  ))

mean(NNT_combined_df$NNT_combined)
# mean returns 3.102308 which is unexpected
# I would've thought 1/RD should be 1/-0.04342125 which = -23.0302
```

Comment: Are you wondering why the average of the inverse sample is not the inverse of the averaged sample?